# Need help updating Router.js for upgrade to Meteor 1.0 and iron:router package

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm in the midst of updating from Meteor 8.2 to Meteor 1.0. I've removed all my old meteorite packages and installed the relevant meteor package system packages. I had to install the new iron-router package and I'm getting the following error in my console on meteor run:

> Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?

The migration notes for the package say: "onBeforeAction hooks now require you to call this.next(), and no longer take a pause() argument."

I tried following the example by remove `pause` from the function and adding `this.next();` after the `else` statement, but to no avail.

How to edit my router so it uses the new onBeforeAction hook? Also, anything else you can call out from the migration that might be problematic would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Here's my router file:

```
/*****************************************************************************/
/* Client and Server Routes */
/*****************************************************************************/
// TODO: use these as per the Event Mind CLI tool.
//Router.configure({
//  templateNameConverter: 'upperCamelCase',
//  routeControllerNameConverter: 'upperCamelCase'
//});

Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
    notFoundTemplate: 'devMain',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading'
});

Router.onRun(function () {Session.set("waiting-on", null); });
Router.onBeforeAction(function() { Alerts.clearSeen(); });

var filters = {
    nProgressHook: function (pause) {
        // we're done waiting on all subs
        if (this.ready()) {
            NProgress.done();
        } else {
            NProgress.start();
            pause(); // stop downstream funcs from running
        }
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(filters.nProgressHook);

Meteor.startup(function () {
    Router.map(function () {
        this.route('loading');

        // reset password urls use hash fragments instead of url paths/query
        // strings so that the reset password token is not sent over the wire
        // on the http request

        this.route('reset-password', {
            template: 'devMain',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            onRun: function () {
                var token = this.params.hash;
                Meteor.logout(function () {
                    Session.set("viewing-settings", true);
                    Session.set("set-password-token", token);
                    Session.set("settings-set-password", true);
                    // Session.set("enrolling", true) // do something special?
                });
            }
        });

        this.route('verify-email', {
            template: 'devMain',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            action: function () {
                var self = this;
                var token = self.params.hash;
                Accounts.verifyEmail(token, function (err) {
                    if (!err) {
                        Alerts.throw({
                            message: "Your email address is now verified!",
                            type: "success", where: "main",
                            autoremove: 3000
                        });
                        Router.go('home');
                    } else {
                        Alerts.throw({
                            message: "Hmm, something went wrong: \""+err.reason +
                                "\". Try again?",
                            type: "danger", where: "main"
                        });
                        Session.set("viewing-settings", true);
                        Router.go('home');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        this.route('leave-game', {
            template: 'devMain',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            action: function () {
                var self = this;
                var token = self.params.hash;
                Meteor.call("leaveGameViaToken", token, function (err, res) {
                    if (!err) {
                        // Idempotently verify user's email,
                        // since they got the token via email.
                        Accounts.verifyEmail(token);
                        if (res.error) {
                            // e.g. "Leave-game link is for unknown game"
                            Alerts.throw({
                                message: res.error.reason, type: "danger", where: "main"
                            });
                            Router.go("home");
                        } else {
                            Alerts.throw({
                                message: "OK, you are no longer in this game.",
                                type: "success", where: res.gameId
                            });
                            Router.go("devDetail", {_id: res.gameId});
                        }
                    } else {
                        Alerts.throw({
                            message: "Hmm, something went wrong: \""+err.reason + "\".",
                            type: "danger", where: "main"
                        });
                        Router.go("home");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        this.route('game-on', {
            template: 'devMain',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            action: function () {
                var self = this;
                var token = self.params.hash;
                Meteor.call("gameOnViaToken", token, function (err, res) {
                  if (err || (res && res.error)) {
                    errorMessage = err ? "Hmm, something went wrong: \"" + err.reason + "\"." : res.error.reason;

                    Alerts.throw({
                      message: errorMessage, type: "danger", where: "main"
                    });

                    Router.go("home");
                  } else {
                    Alerts.throw({
                      message: "Woohoo! Players will be notified.",
                      type: "success", where: res.gameId
                    });

                    Router.go("devDetail", {_id: res.gameId, token: token });
                  }
                });
            }
        });

        this.route('cancel-game', {
            template: 'devMain',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            action: function () {
                var self = this;
                var token = self.params.hash;
                Meteor.call("cancelGameViaToken", token, function (err, res) {
                    if (!err) {
                        Accounts.verifyEmail(token);
                        if (res.error) {
                            Alerts.throw({
                                message: res.error.reason, type: "danger", where: "main"
                            });
                            Router.go("home");
                        } else {
                            Alerts.throw({
                                message: "OK, your game is now cancelled, and players "
                                    + "will be notified.",
                                type: "success", where: "main"
                            });
                            Router.go("home");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Alerts.throw({
                            message: "Hmm, something went wrong: \""+err.reason + "\".",
                            type: "danger", where: "main"
                        });
                        Router.go("home");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // quite similar to 'leave-game' route
        this.route('unsubscribe-all', {
            template: 'devMain',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            action: function () {
                var self = this;
                var token = self.params.hash;
                Meteor.call("unsubscribeAllViaToken", token, function (err, res) {
                    if (!err) {
                        // Idempotently verify user's email,
                        // since they got the token via email.
                        Accounts.verifyEmail(token);
                        if (res.error) {
                            // e.g. "Token provided in link is not an unsubscribe-all token"
                            Alerts.throw({
                                message: res.error.reason, type: "danger", where: "main"
                            });
                            Router.go("home");
                        } else {
                            Alerts.throw({
                                message: "OK, you will no longer receive emails "
                                    + "from Push Pickup.",
                                type: "success", where: "main"
                            });
                            Router.go("home");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Alerts.throw({
                            message: "Hmm, something went wrong: \""+err.reason + "\".",
                            type: "danger", where: "main"
                        });
                        Router.go("home");
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        this.route('enroll-account', {
            template: 'devMain',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            onRun: function () {
                var token = this.params.hash;
                Meteor.logout(function () {
                    Session.set("viewing-settings", true);
                    Session.set("set-password-token", token);
                    Session.set("settings-set-password", true);
                    // Session.set("enrolling", true) // do something special?
                });
            }
        });

        // the home page. listing and searching for games
        this.route('home', {
            path: '/',
            template: 'devMain',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout'
        });

        // typical user interaction with a single game
        this.route('devDetail', {
            path: '/g/:_id/:token?',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            onRun: function () {
                Session.set("joined-game", null);
            },
            waitOn: function () {
                return Meteor.subscribe('game', this.params._id);
            },
            onBeforeAction: function (pause) {
                Session.set("soloGame", this.params._id);
            },
            data: function () {
              var game = Games.findOne(this.params._id);

              if (game) {
                Session.set("gameExists", true);
              }

              return game;
            },
            action: function () {
              var token = this.params.token;

              if (Session.get("gameExists")) {
                this.render();

              } else {
                Router.go('home');

                Alerts.throw({
                  message: "Game not found",
                  type: "warning", where: "top"
                });
              }

              if (token) {
                Meteor.call("sendReminderEmailsViaToken", token, function (err, res) {
                  var errorMessage;

                  Accounts.verifyEmail(token);

                  if (err || (res && res.error)) {
                    errorMessage = err ? "Hmm, something went wrong: \"" + err.reason + "\"." : res.error.reason;

                    Alerts.throw({
                      message: errorMessage, type: "danger", where: "main"
                    });

                    Router.go("home");
                  }
                });
              }
            },
            onStop: function () {
              Session.set("soloGame", null);
              Session.set("gameExists", null);
            }
        });

        this.route('devAddGame', {
            path: '/addGame',
            template: 'devEditableGame',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            onRun: function () {
                Session.set("selectedLocationPoint", null);
                Session.set("newGameDay", null);
                Session.set("newGameTime", null);
                InviteList.remove({});
            },
            waitOn: function() {
                Meteor.subscribe('recently-played');
            },
            data: function () {
                return {
                    action: 'add',
                    title: 'Add game',
                    submit: 'Add game'
                };
            }
        });

        this.route('invitePreviousPlayers', {
            path: 'invitePlayers',
            template: 'invitePreviousPlayers',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout'
        });

        this.route('devEditGame', {
            path: '/editGame/:_id',
            template: 'devEditableGame',
            layoutTemplate: 'devLayout',
            onRun: function () {
                Session.set("selectedLocationPoint", null);
            },
            waitOn: function () {
                return Meteor.subscribe('game', this.params._id);
            },
            onBeforeAction: function (pause) {
                Session.set("soloGame", this.params._id);
            },
            data: function () {
                return _.extend({
                    action: 'edit',
                    title: 'Edit game',
                    submit: 'Update game'
                }, Games.findOne(this.params._id));
            },
            action: function () {
                var self = this;
                var user = Meteor.user();
                var game = self.data();
                if (user && user._id === game.creator.userId ||
                    user && user.admin) {
                    self.render();
                } else {
                    Router.go('home');
                }
            }
        });

        this.route('adminView', {
            path: '/admin',
            onBeforeAction: function () {
                var user = Meteor.user();
                if (!user || !user.admin) {
                    this.render('home');
                }
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: my approach will be like, comment all the route code and try to figure out the issues route by route and also try to add `this.next()` to `Router.onBeforeAction` too

Comment: @Sasikanth sounds like a good approach. For adding `this.next();` to `Router.onBeforeAction`, you'll notice I have two statements for `Router.onBeforeAction`:

`Router.onBeforeAction(function() { Alerts.clearSeen(); });`

and 

`Router.onBeforeAction(filters.nProgressHook);`

Would you add it to the first, second, or both? And how so?

Thank you!

Comment: to both. from the docs `If you want to continue calling the next function you must call this.next() in onBeforeAction` . So if you want to call next functions you must add `this.next()` docs link: https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#available-hook-methods

Comment: I call `this.next()` at the end of the both functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New onBeforeAction hook must call this.next(); You must call it in every onBeforeAction. For example your admin route in new Iron Router would look like this:

```
Router.route('/admin', {
    name: 'adminView',
    onBeforeAction: function () {
        var user = Meteor.user();
        if (!user || !user.admin) {
            this.render('home');
        }
        this.next();
    }
});
```

Replace all this.route(...) in Router.map with Router.route('/path', options) and remove Router.map()

Your global onBeforeAction will look like this:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  Alerts.clearSeen();
  this.next();
});
```

Also, you don't need to wrap your routes in Meteor.startup(...). You can remove it.

And there is no pause parameter anymore, instead of pause call this.next() outside condition:

```
var filters = {
    nProgressHook: function () {
        // we're done waiting on all subs
        if (this.ready()) {
            NProgress.done();
        } else {
            NProgress.start();
        }
        this.next();
    }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(filters.nProgressHook);
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the help Tomas. I've to fly today and will be busy this weekend, but I'll implement your suggested changes on Monday evening and accept your answer once I'm able to get things going :)